# How to pass list of paths to a function?

Tags: rust

I want to pass list of directory names to function,
like so:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn test(dirs: &Vec<Path>) {}

fn main() {
    let dirs = vec![Path::new("/tmp"), Path::new("/var/tmp")];
    test(dirs);
}
```

But it does not compile:

```
<anon>:3:5: 4:6 error: the trait bound `[u8]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied [E0277]
<anon>:3     fn test(dirs: &Vec<Path>) {
<anon>:4     }
<anon>:3:5: 4:6 help: see the detailed explanation for E0277
<anon>:3:5: 4:6 note: `[u8]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
<anon>:3:5: 4:6 note: required because it appears within the type `std::sys::os_str::Slice`
<anon>:3:5: 4:6 note: required because it appears within the type `std::ffi::OsStr`
<anon>:3:5: 4:6 note: required because it appears within the type `std::path::Path`
<anon>:3:5: 4:6 note: required by `std::vec::Vec`
```

Looks like Path not `Sized`?

How should I fix this, if I do not want to pass `Vec<String>` to function?
Maybe `PathBuf`? How to implement this in rusty way?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, `Path` is an unsized type, just like `str`. Pretty much  the only sensible way to work with a `Path` is to take a reference to it: `&Path` (just like `&str`). So your example would look like this:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn test(dirs: &[&Path]) {}

fn main() {
    let dirs = vec![Path::new("/tmp"), Path::new("/var/tmp")];
    test(&dirs);
}
```

Not that I also changed the `&Vec<_>` to `&[_]`. A reference to a `Vec` is not more powerful than a slice (`&[_]`), thus the idiomatic way is to pass slices instead of references to vectors.

---

The above solution is the correct way if you don't want to transfer ownership to the `test` function. If you want to transfer ownership (including the string buffer actually saving the path data), you should use `PathBuf`.

Comment: Can you add a dynamic example, where the list is build at runtime?

Comment: @Zelphir it wouldn't be much different. The function declaration (of `test`) would be exactly like in my code above. You would simply fill the `dirs` vector differently. But this is not really what this question is about... I'm a bit confused by your request, sorry.

Comment: btw this was super helpful to a new rust dev, I had run into docs on PathRef and AsRef<> but they were over my head. &Path tapped into my c++ background to references