# doesn't have a size known at compile-time for Vector of own struct

Tags: rust

I am writing my first Rust program (after hello world). I created a simple struct to wrap an "ImageFile" - further logic will be added:

```
use std::path::Path;

pub struct ImageFile {
    size: u64,
    path: Path,
}
```

First i needed to put "Path" as last field. Because size - is of course - not known at runtime.
I need the type to be able to expose certain "meta data" about an image file, like type, extension etc.

The problem is: wherever i want to use `Vec<ImageFile>` i get an error like

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src\image\FileIndex.rs:7:12
    |
7   |     files: Vec<ImageFile>,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
```

this is from

```
use std::{fs};
use crate::index;
use self::super::ImageFile::ImageFile as ImageFile;
/// index of all files for all given dircetories
pub struct FileIndex {
    folders: Vec<String>,
    files: Vec<ImageFile>, //first error here
}

impl FileIndex  {
    pub fn new(folders: Vec<String>) -> FileIndex {
        FileIndex {
            folders,
            files: index(),
        }
    }
...
```

This creates an index of all image files for the given folders.

What is the best way to fix this for my use case?

Comment: Use `PathBuf` instead of `Path`.

Comment: thx! this seemed to fix it - can you make it an answer and add some explanation?

Comment: You would run into the same issue if you tried to use `Vec<Path>` - unsized types can't be stored directly in a Vec, as the compiler wants to know how much memory each element takes up. By adding `Path` to `ImageFile`, `ImageFile` also became an unsized type.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38170221/5397009

Answer (score 1):

This is the best explanation I can [find](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/unsized-types.html).

As explained in the article [Path Implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html) works only for references for unsized types.

Using PathBuf only makes sense if you want to mutate the path for some reason.

The best you can do is defining the ImageFile struct as follows.

```
pub struct ImageFile <'a> {
    size: u64,
    path: &'a Path,
}
```

Comment: "Using PathBuf only makes sense if you want to mutate the path for some reason." Even if you're not modifying the path, `PathBuf` is useful because it's an owned type. Using it gets rid of the need for `ImageFile<'a>` to carry a lifetime.

Comment: what does " 'a " - syntactically it is very ugly imho

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out,What are scenarios in which using &Path makes sense over PathBuf and vice versa?

Comment: "It's important to understand that lifetime annotations are descriptive, not prescriptive. This means that how long a reference is valid is determined by the code, not by the annotations" since Path is a thin wrapper over OsStr it may have static life time. While PathBuf has a pointer to a string in Heap and dropped when it goes out of scope.

Comment: For beginners, my recommendation is "never use lifetimes explicitly (i.e. store references in struct). Store owned types." This requires some `clone()`s sometimes, and therefore less efficient, but is much easier to understand for a beginner and isn't too much inefficient.

Comment: what does this mean for me? should i store "&'aPath" or PathBuf in my struct?

Comment: In your case assuming you are not going to mutate the Path once created and will just read the image files it is optimal to go with "&'a Path". 

If you strongly feel against the use of lifetime parameter (It only exists in compile time") then as suggested by others you can use PathBuf.