# Cannot return value referencing local variable, data owned by current function, for struct method

Tags: rust

The method returns a path converted from a borrowed string.
However I cant return the value because its reference and cant seem to change that.

here's the code snippet for impl for the struct. The edition I'm using is also 2021

**Note: A full code snippet to recreate this error is located at the very bottom of this body**

```
    pub fn path(&self) -> &'a path::Path {
      let string = self
        .additional
        .get(&DataHashMap::DataPath::ROOT_PATH.to_string())
        .unwrap()
        .clone();

      string.to_owned().push_str(self.data);

      return path::Path::new(&string);
    }
```

The error I get is as follows

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `string`
   --> src\data.rs:484:14
    |
484 |       return path::Path::new(&string);
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------^
    |              |               |
    |              |               `string` is borrowed here
    |              returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I did try dereferencing the value whether or not I did so correctly but it didn't work. I also don't completely understand dereferencing.

```
    pub fn path(&self) -> &'a path::Path {
      let string = self
        .additional
        .get(&DataHashMap::DataPath::ROOT_PATH.to_string())
        .unwrap()
        .clone();

      string.to_owned().push_str(self.data);
      let output_string = (*string.to_string()).to_string();

      return path::Path::new(&output_string);
    }
```

I tried to use a plain borrowed string and didn't get an error

```
    pub fn path(&self) -> &'a path::Path {
      let test = "lib.rs";

      return path::Path::new(test);
    }
```

however if I make the borrowed to string a String and borrow it when I return, then I get the error again. I still don't understand why this happens
I tried to use a plain borrowed string and didn't get an error

```
  pub fn path(&self) -> &'a path::Path {
      let test = "lib.rs".to_string();

      return path::Path::new(&test);
        
  }
```

Code to recreate error:

```
mod TestProgramDataCreation {
  use std::{collections::HashMap, marker::PhantomData, path};

  // naming scheme for the keys in the hashmap
  mod TestDataHashMap {
    pub mod TestDataPath {
      pub const ROOT_PATH: &str = "data_path__root_path";
    }
  }

  pub struct Data;

  pub struct TestDataPath;

  pub struct TestProgramData<'a, T> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<T>,
    data: &'a str,
    additional: HashMap<String, String>,
  }

  impl<'a, T> TestProgramData<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(data: &'a str) -> Self {
      TestProgramData::<T> {
        _phantom: PhantomData::default(),
        data,
        additional: HashMap::new(),
      }
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> &str {
      self.data
    }
  }

  impl<'a, TestDataPath> TestProgramData<'a, TestDataPath> {
    // get the "full" path of the of the directory or file name stored in data field
    pub fn new_path(data: &'a str, root_path: &'a str) -> Self {
      // add root path to hashmap
      let mut additional_hashmap = HashMap::new();
      additional_hashmap.insert(
        TestDataHashMap::TestDataPath::ROOT_PATH.to_string(),
        root_path.to_string(),
      );

      TestProgramData::<TestDataPath> {
        _phantom: PhantomData::default(),
        data,
        additional: additional_hashmap,
      }
    }

    pub fn path(&self) -> &'a path::Path {
      let string = self
        .additional
        .get(&TestDataHashMap::TestDataPath::ROOT_PATH.to_string())
        .unwrap()
        .clone();

      string.to_owned().push_str(self.data);

      return path::Path::new(&string);
    }
  }
}

mod ErrorRecreation {
    // file is called stackoverflow.rs for the purpose of the question
  use crate::stackoverflow::TestProgramDataCreation::TestDataPath;

  use super::TestProgramDataCreation::TestProgramData;

  fn main() {
    let test_root = "./";
    let test: TestProgramData<TestDataPath> =
      TestProgramData::<TestDataPath>::new_path("something", test_root);

    println!("test to recreate error: {:?}", test.path())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in your code.

First, your line `string.to_owned.push_str(self.data)` is a no-op. You copy the string with the `to_owned` call, add the characters from `self.data` to the copy, and then drop the copy. I assume you want to return `string` with `self.data` appended to the end; this method won’t do it. To fix this, declare `string` using `let mut` and then call `string.push_str` directly.

Second, you are returning a `&’a Path`. This means the path you return must live as long as `*self.data` does. However, the lifetime of the path you actually returned is tied to the lifetime of `string`, which ends when the function returns and is thus too short.

To fix this, you should return a `PathBuf`. You can convert a `String` to a `PathBuf` using `PathBuf::from`.

```rust
   pub fn path(&self) -> path::PathBuf {
      let mut string: String = self
        .additional
        .get(&DataHashMap::DataPath::ROOT_PATH.to_string())
        .unwrap()
        .clone();
   
      string.push_str(self.data);

      path::PathBuf::from(string)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But what's the difference between Path and PathBuf?

Comment: A `&Path` is a reference to some other data, a `PathBuf` owns the data, similar to how `&str` is a reference to some other data while `String` owns it.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76754260/5397009

Answer (score -1):

From path::Path::new:

```
pub fn new<S: AsRef<OsStr> + ?Sized>(s: &S) -> &Path {
    unsafe { &*(s.as_ref() as *const OsStr as *const Path) }
}
```

Path::new borrows `string` and returns a `Path`. The lifetime of the returned `Path` is bounded by the lifetime of `string`(which is dropped at the end of the function).

In this case:

```
pub fn path(&self) -> &'a path::Path {
      let test = "lib.rs";

      return path::Path::new(test);
}
```

`test` has a `'static` lifetime. Therefore you can return `&Path` here.

Comment: the `.clone()` fixed a lifetime error, but even if a `'static` lifetime annotation is added in the type for the variable it throws an error saying it may not live long enough. The error in my question is also still there.

Comment: Even if you clone it, `string` is still a local variable, which is dropped when the function exits. `test` has a `'static` lifetime because it is referencing a string literal. `string` is referencing a heap allocated `String`, which has to be dropped.