# Cannot move out mutable reference, when trying to get value inside of Cell

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get the value inside of a `Cell`, but I only get `get_mut` as a method and receive the error below as well.

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*data` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src\stack.rs:17:28
   |
17 |         file_dir.push_str(&data.get_mut().unwrap());
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `data` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
   |
help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference
   |
16 |     PANIC_ERROR_OUTPUT.with(|data: &mut Cell<Option<String>>| {
   |                                     +++
```

Changing `data` to a mutable reference just throws another error saying that the types expected and given don't match. I've also tried dereferencing and cloning with no luck.

The full snippet is:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

thread_local! {
  pub static PANIC_ERROR_OUTPUT: Cell<Option<String>> = Cell::new(None);
}

pub fn set_error_file_dir(dir: &str) {
    PANIC_ERROR_OUTPUT.with(|data| {
        data.set(Some(dir.to_string()));
    });
}

pub fn get_error_file_directory() -> String {
    let mut file_dir = String::new();

    PANIC_ERROR_OUTPUT.with(|data: &Cell<Option<String>>| {
        file_dir.push_str(&data.get_mut().unwrap());
    });

    return file_dir;
}
```

The error seems to be similar to another one I've expeirenced before,
[Cannot return value referencing local variable, data owned by current function, for struct method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76758400/17443354)

Comment: [`get_mut`'s docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.get_mut) say "this method expects `self` to be mutable, which is generally not the case when using a `Cell`." The implication here is that if you have a `&mut Cell` ref you're probably using `Cell` wrong and should be using something else. (This is not an answer. It's just a nudge that adding `mut` isn't the answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::cell::Cell` doesn't work like this. It is almost only useful with data that is `Copy`. It's method [get](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.get) require `T: Copy` and the description says

> Returns a copy of the contained value.

`Cell` accomplishes [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) by returning copy of the contained value, and since it never produces references to data it contains (with the exception of [get_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.get_mut), but as the documentation states this is only useful if you already have a mutable reference to the `Cell` itself), you cannot violate references aliasing rules.

Since you want to store `String`, which is not `Copy`, you cannot use `Cell` to do that. If you want to initialize you data only once (which is probably the case since you are using a thread local and are storing `String` in an `Option`) you should take a look at [OnceCell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html), which should give you exactly the API you are looking for. However if you want to write multiple times to the cell, you should probably use [RefCell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) or even [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), depending on your requirements.

Comment: Could I in theory still use `Cell` while only setting its value once? or would OnceCell still be a better option?

Comment: @mrtomblue you can construct ([and do a couple of other things](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#impl-Cell%3CT%3E)) a `Cell` with a type that is not `Copy`, but you cannot take it from `Cell` having only a shared reference to it. `Cell` is a really specialized data structure and most often than not you actually want something else (if you really need `Cell`, you will know why). I cannot be certain, but I have a strong feeling, based on what you have provided, that you should use `OnceCell`.

Comment: okay thanks, for explanations and links